# chunked file upload using filesupload blueimp and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to do the chunk file upload using blueimp file upload and  Spring mvc but i am getting Bad Request error .

if any one have example of chunk file upload using Spring MVC or java servlet or struts then, please share with me.

I have tried to find the documents but could'nt able to get much details on the same.

Request mapping Done like Below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/upload", "/mobile/upload" }, headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
public ModelAndView uploadFile(
            @RequestParam MultipartFile mpFile,
            @RequestParam String name,
            @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="-1") int chunks,
            @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="-1") int chunk,
            HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Thanks